# Problems when trying to filter strings in a list?

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x, text

I have a large list with strings and I would like to filter everything inside a parenthesis, thus I am using the following regex:

```
text_list = [' 1__(this_is_a_string) 74_string__(anotherString_with_underscores) question__(stringWithAlot_of_underscores) 1.0__(another_withUnderscores) 23:59:59__(get_arguments_end) 2018-05-13 00:00:00__(get_arguments_start)']

import re
r = re.compile('\([^)]*\)')
a_lis = list(filter(r.search, text_list))
print(a_lis)
```

I test my regex [here](https://regex101.com/), and is working. However, when I apply the above regex I end up with an empty list:

```
[]
```

Any idea of how to filter all the tokens inside parenthesis from a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is OK (though perhaps you don't want to capture the parentheses as part of the match), but `search()` is the wrong method to use.  You want `findall()` to get the text of all the matches, rather than the indices of the first match:

```
list(map(r.findall, text_list))
```

This will give you a list of lists, where each inner list contains the strings which were inside parentheses.

For example, given this input:

```
text_list = ['asdf (qwe) asdf (gdfd)', 'xx', 'gdfw(rgf)']
```

The result is:

```
[['(qwe)', '(gdfd)'], [], ['(rgf)']]
```

If you want to exclude the parentheses, change the regex slightly:

```
'\(([^)]*)\)'
```

The unescaped parentheses within the escaped ones indicate what to capture.

Comment: how should I modify my regex if I only want to extract: `[['qwe', 'gdfd'], [], ['rgf']]`

Comment: @tumbleweed: I've updated my answer to tell you how to remove the parentheses.